# Accessing top-level fields in AppSettings.json from injected configuration class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1, application-settings

Say we have such AppSettings.json

```json
{
  "Region": Europe,
  "WeirdService": {
    "JustField": "value"
  }
}
```

Registering `WeirdService` settings in separate, singleton class (or using options pattern) is fine, just:

```cs
service.AddSingleton(configuration.GetSection("WeirdService").Get<WeirdService>();
```

And at this point it's fine. I don't know however how to deal cleanly with this top-level properties like `Region` in my example.

I know I can just inject `IConfiguration` and use `config.GetValue<string>("Region")` or just access configuration directly, but I wonder if there is some clean, better way without hardcoding this stuff in services.

#### Edit

I forgot to mention. Team I'm currently working with uses .NET Core 3.1 as it's current LTS release.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be to just create a class for the toplevel keys. In your case you could create something like AppConfig with the single property Region. Then you just register it without getting a config section using the Configuration object, the Configure methods asks for a Configuration interface anyway and not a ConfigurationSection.

AppConfig:

```
public class AppConfig
{
    public string? Region { get; set; }
}
```

Registration:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddOptions(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    return services.Configure<AppConfig>(configuration);
}
```

Usage:

```
public class ExampleConsumer
{
    public ExampleConsumer(IOptions<AppConfig> appConfig) {}
}
```

Comment: Hey, I think the issue maybe somewhere else. The point of this is that you can bind an options class to the top level configuration values of an IConfiguration instance, there is no need to put everything one level down.

Answer (score 4):

You got two options

### Don't have any top level fields

All top level fields would go one level in. Your configuration would look something like:

```json
{
  "App": {
    "Region": "east-us-2",
    "ShowMaintenancePrompt": false
  },
  // other options follow
}
```

The advantage of this approach is you can keep adding to `"App"` as your application grows, and continue to use the options pattern.

### Gather top-level fields into a class, and register that with DI

For a configuration like:

```json
{
  "Region": "east-us-2"
}
```

Create a AppConfig class like:

```cs
internal class AppConfig
{
    public string? Region { get; set; }
}
```

And register this class with the DI:

```cs
var toplevelConfig = new AppConfig {
    Region = configuration.GetValue<string>("Region")
};
services.AddSingleton<AppConfig>(toplevelConfig);
```

You can now inject `AppConfig` anywhere you'd like.

The only minor downside to this is that you cannot use the options pattern anymore.

Avoid injecting `IConfiguration` directly.

Comment: Hi, seems like the best answer so far. I would prefer to use first option, but I inherited some project and second one seems like a little less hassle for now. My take was to create singleton settings with IConfiguration injected just to extract needed fields., but your version looks better.

Answer (score 0):

### Updated

### Method 1 Preferred way

The preferred way to read related configuration values is using the `options pattern`.

For more detail about the `options pattern` check the link below.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-5.0

```
 "WeirdService": {
     "JustField": "value"
  }
```

Create the `WeiredServiceOptions` class.

```
public class WeiredServiceOptions
{
   public const string WeiredService = "WeiredService";
   public string JustField { get; set; }
}
```

An options class:

1. Must be non-abstract with a public parameterless constructor.
2. All public read-write properties of the type are bound.
3. Fields are not bound. In the preceding code, `WeiredService` is not bound. The Position property is used so the string **WeiredService** doesn't need to be hardcoded in the app when binding the class to a configuration provider.

Calls `ConfigurationBinder.Bind` to bind the `WeiredServiceOption`s class to the WeiredService section.

```
var weiredServiceOptions = new PositionOptions();
configuration.GetSection(PositionOptions.Position).Bind(positionOptions);
```

An alternative approach when using the options pattern is to bind the WeiredService section and add it to the `dependency injection service container`. In the following code, WeiredServiceOptions is added to the service container with Configure and bound to the configuration

```
services.Configure<WeiredServiceOptions>(Configuration.GetSection(
                                    WeiredServiceOptions.Position));
```

and then read the WeiredService Options.

```
private readonly WeiredServiceOptions _options;

public YourClassContructor(IOptions<WeiredServiceOptions> options)
{
   _options = options
}

Console.WriteLine($"JustField: {_options.JustField}");
```

### Method 2

service.AddSingleton(configuration.GetSection("WeirdService:JustField").value);

### Method 3

```
service.AddSingleton(configuration["WeirdService:JustField"]);
```

Comment: Hi, I didn't asked how to access ```WeirdService``` properties. That's the thing I know. I asked for good way to access property "Region" which is top-level in appsettings.

Beside that, your code is wrong. It could be harmful even...

Comment: How it's harmful and what thing is wrong?

Comment: Simply because ```service.AddSingleton(configuration["WeirdService:JustField"]);``` would implicitly set string as generic parameter for this singleton. So now whenever you set string as argument in service constructor, it would try to pass ```WeirdService:JustField``` value. I have done something like that in past and honestly it wasn't pretty. I don't remember what did broke, but results were wild and quite unexpected.

Comment: Check this link ms docs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: Also, I have updated my please check with the reference of ms docs.

Answer (score 0):

Doing: `services.AddSingleton(Configuration.GetSection("WeirdService").Get<WeirdService>());`
will register `WeirdService` to the Ioc container without supporting Options pattern. Assuming this is what you are looking for. Here is what you could do:

1. Create a class with properties mathcing the top level configuration similar to the `AppConfig` class a couple of people have suggested in the answers
2. Register the `AppConfig` class with the Ioc as below:

   ```cs
   services.AddSingleton(Configuration.Get<AppConfig>());
   ```

Note:

- Doing `Configuration.Get<AppConfig>()` will bind matching properties on the AppConfig class with the corresponding values from appsettings.json

  - Feel free to skip properties for keys that you do not want to bind
- The `IConfiguration.Get<T>` is an extension method defined in  `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBinder` just in case

Answer (score -1):

You can bind section to a class as well, it allows clean usage without using much of the  magic strings.

```
public class WeirdService{
 public string JustField{ get; set;}  
 public string AnotherField{ get; set;}
 }
```

In controller you can then define a field

```
private readonly WeirdService _weirdService = new WeirdService();
 public UserController(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    configuration.GetSection("WeirdService").Bind(_weirdService);
    
    //_weirdService.JustField
    //_weirdService.AnotherField
}
```

You can access Region field using

```
configuration.GetValue<string>("Region")
```

or other way is

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment 
 webHostEnvironment)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        environment = webHostEnvironment;
    }
```

then you can just use

> Configuration["Region"]

Comment: Thanks for answer, but that doesn't even ring close. I specifically asked how to properly access ```Region```, top-level appsettings variable, not ```WeirdService```. Beside that, I already provided solution similar for what you sent.

Comment: I have edited the answer to match your requirement , you can access any top level value with this but for section values it is wise to use class to avoid strings